# How to Specify Checkbox List Values in JTable Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery-jtable

I am using JTable Jquery plugin, and one of the columns is a checkbox. When creating/editing, this column should show a list of checkboxes of names of locations, which the user can un/check. I've set the `type` to `checkbox` as shown below. What else do I need to do to make the checklist show?

```
location: {
   title: 'Location(s)',
   width: '50%',
   type: 'checkbox',
   options: 'http://localhost/proj/locations'
  },
```

The `options` property returns a list of all the locations. Or how does one specify the list of values to be used? If type was `radiobutton`, this works alright. When it is `checkbox`, doesn't work. What else do I need to provide? The docs say one can provide 3 additional options, but these are optional too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use checkbox then `location` field should be **Boolean** field. Check this [link](http://jtable.org/Tutorials/UsingWithAspNetWebFormsPageMethods). 
Following is example for checkbox:

```
location: {
              title: 'Location(s)',
              width: '50%',
              type: 'checkbox',
              values: { 'false': 'False', 'true': 'True' },
              defaultValue: 'true'
          },
```

And you can not use `options` property with `checkbox` type. 
You can only use options property with `radiobutton` type or dropdown.

Comment: Thanks for that. My issue becomes, the answer seems to only cover when I want to display one checkbox. What if I want to display a list of many checkboxes, which are generated dynamically?

Comment: @gthuo There is no functionality available for multiple dynamic checkboxes, Either you will need to create model for that or need to handle it in [display function](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/FieldOptions#fopt-display)

Comment: Ok, looks like something with quite some use case and probably ought to have some inbuilt handling method. Anyhow, the display may help